# elements of an array if statement

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int i,l,t=1,m,a[15]={0};
    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {  
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>=3 && a[i]<=8)
        {
            for(l=i+1;l<15;l++)
            {
                if(a[i]>a[l])
                {
                    m=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[l];
                    a[l]=m;
                }
            }
            printf(" No%d \t %d \n",t++,a[i]);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

In this code in c i want to print the elements of an array in an ascending order but the value of the elements must be bewteen 3 and 8. The results that i get exclude the values over 8 but they include the values under 3.Why does this happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My eyes, your formatting is terrible. Please fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you do the sorting separately, then just print the elements between 3 and 8, then you will get it in the order you would want.

```
// sort the array
for(i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    for(l=i+1;l<15;l++)
    {
        if(a[i]>a[l])
        {
            m=a[i];
            a[i]=a[l];
            a[l]=m;
        }
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    if (a[i] < 3)
        continue;

    if (a[i] > 8)
        break;

    printf(" No%d \t %d \n",t++,a[i]);
}
```

EDIT: modified print loop

Comment: If array is sorted you can have a better loop for printing i.e. lesser iterations in some cases, ignore till `a[i]` is >= 3, then print only till `a[i]` is <=8

Comment: yes. i've changed the code. I could have iterated till `a[i] < 3` outside the main loop, this would avoid that check later on, but I think that would be called premature optimization. So I've left that

Comment: True! :) ... Was just making an observation thats all

Comment: Thank you all very much for the quick answers :) .It was so simple but i tend to make things complicated and not think clearly.Also i am sorry for the formatting.

Comment: I always keep in mind that often the simplest solution is the best solution :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running some kind of a sorting algorithm in there, but you skip all elements between 3 and 8.

The reason you see numbers under 3 printed is because your `printf` is after the loop that does swapping: by the time the inner loop is finished, a number that's smaller than `a[i]` may be inserted at `i`-th position. If you move `printf` before the loop, the numbers printed will all be from the `[3..8]` range, inclusive of both ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop excludes both 3 and 8 from your sort:

```
for(i=0;i<15;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>=3 && a[i]<=8) /* <--- exclusion here */
    {
        /* code nested in outer loop and exclusion */
    }
}
```

However, your inner loop has no such exclusion:

```
for(l=i+1;l<15;l++)
{
    if(a[i]>a[l]) /* <--- no exclusion! */
    {
        m=a[i];
        a[i]=a[l];
        a[l]=m;
    }
}
```

I suggest modifying your inner loop to exclude values below 3 from it's search:

```
for(l=i+1;l<15;l++)
{
    if(a[l]>=3 && a[i]>a[l])
    {
        m=a[i];
        a[i]=a[l];
        a[l]=m;
    }
}
```